# Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, node-modules

I am trying to start NodeJS package from Azure DevOps with a inline powershell script.

Here is the script I've setup on Azure DevOps :

```
$backendFolder = "C:\path\to\backend"
$nodejsExecutable = "C:\Program Files\nodejs"

Set-location $backendFolder
Start-Process -FilePath $nodejsExecutable -ArgumentList "run","build" -wait -NoNewWindow -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose -WorkingDirectory $backendFolder
Start-Process -FilePath $nodejsExecutable -ArgumentList "run","start" -wait -NoNewWindow -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose -WorkingDirectory $backendFolder
```

Below is the output of the error :

```
2023-01-14T18:32:10.5104498Z Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied.
2023-01-14T18:32:10.5105828Z At C:\azagent\A3\_work\_temp\861703e2-7a4b-4544-b9d4-5722c8768a5a.ps1:8 char:1
2023-01-14T18:32:10.5106472Z + Start-Process -FilePath $nodejsExecutable -ArgumentList "run","build" ...
2023-01-14T18:32:10.5106954Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-01-14T18:32:10.5107500Z     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
2023-01-14T18:32:10.5108092Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I've tried numerous things, from adding the $path in environment variables, allowing full permissions to both folders in "C:\Program Files\nodejs" & "C:\path\to\backend" but same results.

**Note # It's running on Windows and a IIS web server! On Azure DevOps I've created this steps - Stop IIS, Stop Node, Create IIS web app, Deploy IIS web app, Start Node & run the 2 powershell scripts to build & start the NodeJS app.**

Any idea what's going on here or what I'm I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused due to the credential are trying to use.  **Start-Process** starts the program as similar to the **Invoke-Item**.

use the parameters of **Start-Process** to specify options, such as loading a user profile, starting the process using alternate credentials.

Example like

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$args = *********************
Start-Process ****** -Credential $cred -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList $args
```

refer this [syntax's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3) from official site.

Here the tutorial of [Configure](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vsts/nodejs/) CI/CD for Node application with Azure Pipelines for more information.

Comment: Thanks @swarna-anipindi, thanks for the details, I've tried this but no go. I will answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

So I've done 2 things to fix this issue, maybe 3 things.

1. I've removed the complete agent setup and ran it as the actual user on the VM, previously I've set it up with the System user (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM).

> NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

2. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30933225/12897722) to add the user to impersonate the account. Remember to run `gpupdate /force` & restart the `Azure Agent` service under Services.

> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> "Impersonate a client after authentication"

3. I've changed the `$nodejsExecutable = "C:\Program Files\nodejs"` to `$nodejsExecutable = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd"` but it might be different in other cases.

Thanks.